# Hive Mac Wallet Migration

Tags: hive

So I left Bitcoin for a while, and had transferred some of my bitcoin into a Hive-Mac wallet.  Well I recently found out that Hive discontinued development and that the previous versions are no longer compatible with the newer versions of OSX.

I noticed that Hive-Mac used the bitcoinj library, and ostensibly this is the format that the wallet is in too.

Would I have any luck trying to recover the wallet into another application that runs on the bitcoinj library (and if so, any recommendations on which app), or do I need to try and run an older version of OSX so I can get the old version to build, then go from there?

Answer (score 2):

You're in luck, because I had a similar issue, and just finished making a tool to export private keys from old hive wallets. First, you should search your system for bitcoinkit.wallet, which is the file Hive used to store the wallet.

Then, go here and follow my instructions.
https://github.com/JesseCorrington/bitcoinj-wallet-export

Let me know if it doesn't work, I only tested this on my wallet, which was a non deterministic wallet with encrypted private keys. If you had a different type of wallet it likely will not work. Bug me if that's the case and I can see about updating my code.

Comment: Hi Jesse, thanks for your answer, this looks helpful to the asker. I've removed the donation address from your post, not because you don't deserve some coming your way but because we don't allow donation addresses in posts in general. Please feel free to post a donation address on your user profile, thank you.

Comment: @Murch, Rules noted, and thanks for editing my post rather than just removing it.

Comment: @AndrewRichmond, I don't remember the location where Hive stores the wallet file by default, it's been a while since I worked on this. Just search in spotlight (cmd+space) for bitcoinkit.wallet. Or you can open a new finder window and search your hard drive from the search bar. Either should work find to locate the wallet file if it exists. BitcoinJKit isn't the right file.